How to calculate the TVL in Astar dapp staking?
Is it possible to calculate the TVL of dapp staking on Astar using the data from the storage function dappStaking.contractStake, and if so, how would one do it?

No, it's not possible since tokens can be locked, without being staked.
You should read CurrentEraInfo storage, and take the totalLocked field value as TVL in dApp staking.

